# Why is Quick Explosion going backwards?

Tags: mesh, objects

Example: https://gyazo.com/0bb3bba306114688b1ef48960887fd2b why is this going backwards ?? I only want it to explode on the same spot now to move

Well i added a quick explode into that Cube ( castle entrance ) and everytime i press " play " it does backwards instead of exploding in the same spot .. I just want that the mesh will explode on that spot and fell down

Comment: Can you share more information with us please?

Comment: Well i added a quick explode into that Cube ( castle entrance ) and everytime i press " play " it does backwards instead of exploding in the same spot .. I just want that the mesh will explode on that spot and fell down

Comment: @Paulo: Repeating the question is not the same as giving more information. If a user asks for more information, it's because what was in the question wasn't enough. "Sharing more information" means actually providing information that wasn't previously there.